# Parameters inside SetServiceStatus

Tags: c#, windows-services

I was reading up on the Windows Service Application on MSDN, where I came across this following piece of code:

```
 [DllImport("advapi32.dll", SetLastError = true)]
    private static extern bool SetServiceStatus(System.IntPtr handle, ref ServiceStatus serviceStatus);
```

I understood that Servicestatus is used to set the status of the service at different points in it's life cycle.

However, I am not able to understood the use of **System.IntPtr handle**. Please help me as I am new in this topic. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Unless you have a specific reason for using DllImport, I would suggest to use the already available wrapper **ServiceController** found in ***System.ServiceProcess*** assembly.

Then to set the status of a service simply pass in the service name as follows:

```
ServiceController serviceController = new ServiceController("MyServiceName");
serviceController.Start();
serviceController.Stop();
```

Ideally before starting or stopping a service you should check the status beforehand. To do this you can use the following method:

```
public ServiceControllerStatus GetServiceStatus(string serviceName)
{
    ServiceController[] services = ServiceController.GetServices();
    using (ServiceController service = services.FirstOrDefault(s => s.ServiceName == serviceName))
    {
        if (service != null)
        {
            using (ServiceController sc = new ServiceController(service.ServiceName))
            {
                return sc.Status;
            }
        }
        else
        {
            //Here you can either throw an exception or return default(ServiceControllerStatus).
        }          
    }
}
```

Comment: i was actually just learning about how to create windows services. But yeah I will certainly try out using the serviceController. But I would still want to know what exactly does the handle do.